# Get Golang flags as byte array

Tags: arrays, go, hex, byte, slice

I am using `flag` package to read all the parameters I am passing to my Golang program. The problem is that if I pass an argument such as `"\x41BC"`, it is not read as a 3 byte array (with chars `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`), but as a 6 byte array (`'\'`, `'x'`, `'4'`, `'1'`, `'B'`, `'C'`).

If it could be useful to answer, I am reading that string using:

```
flag.StringVar(&param, "param", "", "the param with hex chars")
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"\x41BC"` is a quoted string. The [`flag`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package does not do any unquoting, it will just hand you over the arguments that were specified when starting your application. You can use the [`strconv.Unquote()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Unquote) and [`strconv.UnquoteChar()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#UnquoteChar) functions to unquote them.

One thing you should be aware of is that `strconv.Unquote()` can only unquote strings that are in quotes (e.g. start and end with a quote char `"` or a back quote char `` ` ``),  so we have to manually append that.

See this example:

```
s := `\x41BC`
fmt.Println(s)
s2, err := strconv.Unquote(`"` + s + `"`)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(s2)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/SVcrEE2gl0)):

```
\x41BC
ABC
```

So if you want to be able to provide quoted strings as command line arguments and still have the unquoted values, you have to unquote them with `strconv.Unquote()` after calling [`flag.Parse()`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Parse), for example:

```
var param string
flag.StringVar(&param, "param", "", "the param with hex chars")

flag.Parse()
var err error
param, err = strconv.Unquote(`"` + param + `"`)
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // handle error
}
// param now contains the unquoted argument value
```